# How to add additional conditions inside a forEach loop with altering the callback function?

Tags: javascript, loops, callback

This is the problem I am trying to solve:
"Use forEach to write a function count(arr, callback). It should return the number of elements for which callback is true."
So using forEach is required to solve the problem

Now my problem is that the callback is an argument that is passed to the forEach via higher-order function and I can not modify it.

Below is the flowchart that I think I should implement, would appreciate any hint on how to add conditions inside forEach to add to the counter variable

[image]

Comment: But you can wrap a function around `forEach`, right? Just try something out and show what you've got.

Comment: Why is adding a condition inside of a forEach different than adding a condition anywhere else?

Comment: This is not a homework service

Comment: please add your attempt with data and result.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier
Thank you for the idea, I was not aware that I can do such thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function count(arr, cb){
    let count = 0;
    arr.forEach(item=>{
         if(cb(item)) count++;
    })
    return count
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now I see the point. I need to use callback as an argument to another callback inside the forEach.
Did I get it correctly?